# Drawing cloud on HTML5 <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a symmetrical cloud as part of a landscape on the canvas element using arc but I am not getting beyond the first arc. I have researched answers on the site but nothing came up specifically for drawing a cloud. (I got as far as speech bubble instead).Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please share what code you have.

Comment: Aweary, I am a little unsure of how to reply to your post. So I posted my code as a new question. Thanks !

Comment: Hi newbie and welcome to Stackoverflow! If you have reposted this question, you might want to delete this outdated version by hitting the 'delete' link. This keeps Stackoverflow free of unnecessary duplicate posts. Thanks!